# redirecting to another asp.net page using request.querystring in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, request.querystring

```
int ob=0;

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    ob = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["value"].ToString());

    if (RadioButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        ob = ob + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        ob = ob + 0;
    }
    Response.Redirect("result.aspx?value = " + ob);
}
```

> exception:- System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set
>   to an instance of an object.'
>
> System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.this[string].get
>   returned null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Request.QueryString["value"]
```

It returns null. So when you call ToString() on null it rises exception.

Comment: In the preceeding page, I have written the following code:  Response.Write("ques2.aspx?value =" + ob); so  the variable "value" is carried on to this page.

Comment: Response.Write it is about writing string to HTTP response output stream.
Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1463ysyw(v=vs.110).aspx
So in short words even if you call Response.Write("ques2.aspx?value =" + ob); it does not mean that 'value' exists within Request.QueryString

Comment: You should ensure that you pass value parameter from the previous page.
E.g. on previous page in code behind you need to call
Response.Redirect("your-page.aspx?value=" + "value of value parameter");
In such case on the target page your code - ob = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["value"].ToString()); will work fine.
And of course "value of value parameter" should be an integer.